# Change some levels in a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a DataFrame df whose df.columns is a hierarchical MultiIndex idx (with 2 layers).

```
idx = df.columns
```

This idx.levels is a FrozenList with

```
len(idx.levels) == 2
```

idx.levels[0] is fine, and idx.levels[1] is a Index object with 9 elements. dtype='object'.

```
idx.levels[1] == Index(['Foo1', 'Foo2', 'Foo3', 'Foo4', 'Foo5', 'Foo6', 'Foo7', 'Foo8', 'Foo9'], dtype='object')
```

I need to rename both 'Foo4' and 'Foo5' to 'x1' and 'Foo3' to 'x2'

How do I do that? Of course, I need the original dataframe to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method of DataFrame:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'Foo4':'x1', 'Foo5':'x1', 'Foo3':'x2'})
```